# UIScrollView with autolayout returns frame size including toolbar

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout, ios9

I do have a `UIScrollView` in my `UIViewController`, positioned using AutoLayout:

```
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[scrollView(width)]-0-|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: ["width":CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds)], views: ["scrollView":self.scrollView]))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[continueButton]-0-|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["continueButton":self.continueButton]))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[scrollView]-0-[continueButton(50)]-0-|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView":scrollView, "continueButton":self.continueButton]))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

When I now try to get the `UIScrollView`'s height afterwards:

```
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    print(CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame))
```

The size I'm getting is too high - it includes navigation and status bar. It makes no difference if I set

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

or not, the height I'm getting is always the same and wrong. What am I missing here? How can I get the real `UIScrollView`'s frame?

Comment: First of all do not use `self.view.addConstraints` ever, instead create constraints and activate them through the `active` property or `NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(constraintsArray)`. Second is only a guess, your vertical constraints uses the option `DirectionLeadingToTrailing` but from my knowledge leading and trailing attributes/anchors are for horizontal usage only.